# Accessing Class Variables?

Tags: ruby, class-variables

```
class Foo
  @@default = "default"

  p instance_variables
  p class_variables

  class << self
    p instance_variables
    p class_variables

    # How do I access the @@default variable here?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you do it in any other place: `@@default`.

I'm not sure what `p ..` is supposed to do (Ruby isn't my native language), but this works

```
class Foo
  @@default = "default"

  class << self
    puts "#{@@default}"
  end
end
```

Comment: `p` is a lazy way of writing `puts` :P

Comment: The method "p" calls `#inspect` and then calls `puts()` on the result. It's more of a debugging method whereas `puts()` is a general-purpose output method.

Comment: @Nikita, Can you explain how this class variable is accessible in the singleton class? as far as i understand singleton classes and class variables, it shouldn't be :/

Comment: @banister I have little theoretical knowledge of Ruby (as I said in the answer), but if you run above code you'll see 'default' at console.

Comment: @banister Still, if you consider similar situation in Java (which I do know), accessing static variables from static methods makes sense there.

Comment: @Nikita, yes...but in ruby i dont think it makes sense...i can see it it useful, but i cant make sense of it. :) but yes...it does seem to work :)

Comment: @banister You mean, that because 'singleton methods' are just instance methods of class object, 'singleton variables' should be instance variables of class object and hence referenced with single '@'? Not sure, may be you could ask a question here about that :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of interesting because it essentially asks "is there any way for the metaclass to reference its "real" class?

And as far as I can tell, the answer is "no", because all of the "upward" ancestor pointers Ruby keeps also point to metaclasses, and so running `class_variables()` in one of them will tell you about its *class instance variables*.  So, you have to reference objects by name or just establish a handle before entering the metaclass context...

```
class Foo
  @@default = "default"
  @@me = self

  p instance_variables
  p class_variables

  class << self
    p instance_variables
    p @@me.class_variables
  end
end
```